# How to bind @Value annotated fields of service in unit tests?

Tags: grails, spock

Service:

```
@GrailsCompileStatic
class MyService {
    final static String PLACEHOLDER = '<x>'

    @Value('${myService.url}')  // Suppose it http://example.com/doc-<x>.html 
    private String urlTemplate

    String getSomeUrl(String lang) {
        urlTemplate.replace(PLACEHOLDER, lang)
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
@TestFor(MyService)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    void "test get some url for #lang"() {
        when:
            def someUrl = service.getSomeUrl(lang) // NullPointerException, because urlTemplate is null
        then:
            someUrl.endsWith(lang + '.html')
        where:
            lang << ['es', 'en']
    }
}
```

So, as I mentioned above, `urlTemplate` is null (but config value exists in `.properties`). How to fix it?

---

Solution:

```
class MyServiceSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    MyService myService

    @Unroll
    void "test get some url for #lang"() {
        when:
            def someUrl = myService.getSomeUrl(lang)
        then:
            someUrl.endsWith(lang + '.html')
        where:
            lang << ['es', 'en']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit tests are used to test isolated units of code. If you are testing behavior that is dependent on the configuration value, inject it into the unit test to achieve reusable unit tests.

On the other hand, if you are testing that the variable is actually set or what the variable is set to, you need to use an integration test because you are basically testing your integration with Grails' configuration mechanism: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting

As a third option, you could also use functional testing to verify that in the end everything appears to function as it is supposed to: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html#functionalTesting

Comment: "inject it into the unit test to achieve reusable unit tests" - how can I do that? To be honest, I looking for something like this:   `@DearSpringInjectValuesPlease(from = 'myconfig.properties')`

Comment: The simplest way to inject the value would be as Jeff Scott Brown answered, by simply setting the property. If you insist on loading it from your property file however, an integration test would probably be more suitable because otherwise you would have to bring up Grails' integration mechanism yourself, risking that your code breaks after a version upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

> How to bind @Value annotated fields of service in unit tests?

One way to do it...

```
@TestFor(MyService)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    void "test get some url for #lang"() {
        when:
        service.urlTemplate = 'some value'
        def someUrl = service.getSomeUrl(lang)

        then:
        someUrl.endsWith(lang + '.html')

        where:
        lang << ['es', 'en']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone.

I had an issue where a missing property variable used in a @Value was giving me an BeanExpressionException for a service unit test. I found that setting that variable in my application.yml for the test environment solved my problem in Grails 4.

@Value in question:

```
@Value("#{\${some_property_here}}") public Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> SOME_MAP_OF_MAPS
```